# Loading resident programs and executing them

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

My porpouse is to build assembly code to load 2 other programs to RAM Memory, then executing them from the parent program whenever I choose. I've just started learning assembly language, I'm using NASM 16 bits by the way. I've been doing extensive reading about this and I've found this subject extremely difficult to understand.

This is the link I've been using for documentation: http://maven.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/artofasm.html

Can someone help me doing this?

Any information needed I'll be more than happy to provide.

Comment: What OS/platform do you want to do this in?

Comment: And what is the purpose of this particular requirement?  There may be simpler solutions to your problem.

Comment: @MichaelSlade I'm using Windows 7 32 bits. I'm trying really hard to learn assembly and I've been doing it fine until now. It's quite hard to be honest. I'm trying to complete a series of tutorials and self-stablished goals. Anyway you can help me on how to do this program?

Comment: @MichaelSlade What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you are asking to do is essentially to link a program into memory and later execute it.

linking is the work necessary to translate the program code in a file on disk into something in memory that can be executed.  In modern operating systems this is no small task.

The general consensus is that you should use the operating system to do this.  First, find out how to call windows system calls in assembly (assuming you haven't already).  Then look into these functions:

- [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [LoadLibraryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

And see if they can do what you need.